# GLSL uniform arrays incorrect values

Tags: android, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0, glsl

I am trying to pass light and lightcolor information to my shader via a uniform array.
I declared these in my shader like this:

```
     uniform vec2 lightpositions[4];
     uniform vec4 lightcolors[4];
```

And in my code (C++):

```
float lightpositions[8] = { 
        150, 150,
        (float) screenWidth - 150, 150,
        (float) screenWidth - 150, (float) screenHeight - 150,
        150, (float) screenHeight - 150
};

float lightcolors[16] = {
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0
};

glUniform2fv(lightposHandle, amount, lightpositions);
checkGlError("lightPositions");

glUniform4fv(lightcolorHandle, amount, lightcolors);
checkGlError("lightColors");
```

Where amount is 4 in this case.

When I check my OpenGL ES debugger (PerfHud ES) I see that the values in the arrays are almost random like 1.4e+02.

Am I doing something wrong? Or should I use attributes in this case?

Comment: What's the rest of your code? Are you sure the program is in use when calling `glUniform...`? Do the uniform locations have reasonable values (note: a uniform location of `-1` does *not* cause `glUniform` to generate an error, it's just a no-op in this case)?

Comment: "*I see that the values in the arrays are almost random like 1.4e+02*" That's not random. 1.4e+02 is just scientific notation for 140.

Comment: @NicolBolas I meant random as in the way that these numbers mean nothing to me and include no pattern. Here is my drawing code: [link](http://pastebin.com/5c5Rzbwk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright I solved it.

I created my arrays in a class which I then passed to my Lights class via the constructer.
Where my light class assigns this array to a private float* lightpositions. This was the source of the wrong values, because I think (if someone could make this clear) that I was passing in the address of the array. When I create a normal array (float test[8]) the values passed to the shader are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your shader is looks correct (see section 4.1.9 of the ["ESSL specification"](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf) for a very similar declaration) and so does your API code.

My best guess is that is that something goes wrong when you query the uniform locations, and one or more of the locations are returned as -1. Try checking after each call to glGetUniformLocation if -1 was returned.

(The names used in the calls to glGetUniformLocation in the drawing code you posted do not match the shader code in your questions. This could be the bug you're looking for.)

Comment: Yes you are right. lightposHandle = glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "lightpositions"); returns 0 and lightcolorHandle = glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "lightcolors"); returns -1. Which is strange since the names match 100% and the program is correct to.

Comment: I uploaded my call trace as it might help : [link](http://pastebin.com/g49HCaG3). Everything until the first draw call (line 25) is the problematic code, beyond that are two other objects which I am able to draw just fine.

Comment: The call trace doesn't help much since replaces the string parameters with magic hexvalues. Any chance you could post the full shader and the code that queries the uniform locations?

Comment: See this [link](http://pastebin.com/iGrgjtxs). As you can see is I commented out the lightcolors for testing.

Answer (score -1):

You can not use array notation like this in OpenGL ES 2.0 shader code.  That is a 3.0 feature.

Also, I would try it on another platform with different OpenGL ES drivers. You might also need the precision specifiers, like this:

```
uniform highp vec2 lightpositions[4];
uniform highp vec4 lightcolors[4];
```

For OpenGL ES 3.0, you would need to construct the array as an array of vec3, like this:

```
vec3 lightcolors[6] = 
{ 
    vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), 
    vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f) 
};
```

Comment: It is possible in OpenGL ES 2.0, docs says so. Check out this [link](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/reference_cards/OpenGL-ES-2_0-Reference-card.pdf) at the program session.

Comment: I searched all the OpenGL ES shader code that I have and the only examples I found of using the array notation was for 3.0.  If you find a 2.0 driver or Android device where it works, please let us know.

Comment: Your answer somehow reads as if you seem to think that his array initializations from his *C++* example were from his *GLSL* code (especially the last paragraph), which isn't the case. Declaring uniform arrays in GLSL like he does should be perfectly fine with ES 2.0, [as the specification says](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf).

Comment: I understand that and I agree that arrays are in the 2.0 specification.  My point is that in the entire PowerVR SDK the use of arrays is avoided for 2.0.  We only see it in the 3.0 examples, and I have seen complaints of problems with it from other developers on the Khronos OpenGL ES forum.  I try to avoid using features that are not well supported across platform vendors.